# Getting a "proper" and "permanent" URL for an app hosted in Azure Static Web App

Tags: c#, angular, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-static-web-app

I am developing an Azure-based app:

- Frontend is Angular v16, hosted in an Azure Static Web Site (on Linux)
- Backend is an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API (hosted in an Azure Windows App Service)
- Database is Azure SQL database

I have been able to get this up and running - so far so good. But one issue remains: the frontend Angular app is hosted in an Azure Static Web Site, under a rather "funny" / "unconventional" URL - something like:

```
thankful-salmon-01110a022.9.azurestaticapps.net
black-meadow-0222ebd09.5.azurestaticapps.net
purple-cliff-03333bb17.4.azurestaticapps.net
```

Those are OK as long as I'm in development mode, and even in user testing, I can live with that - but for production, this is a bit too "oddball" to leave as is.

I'm no networking expert by any means - and our networking guys were able to implement a fairly simple URL redirection - so

```
https://myapp-dev.mycompany.com  ---> black-meadow-0222ebd09.5.azurestaticapps.net
https://myapp-test.mycompany.com  ---> thankful-salmon-01110a022.9.azurestaticapps.net
```

This works fine - but the redirection means, in the end, the end user is still seeing (and interacting with) that "oddball" URL (which will also be stored when the endusers bookmark a page or two).

Our company is running its own DNS system - so I can't set up an Azure based "shadow" DNS - but is there any way I can somehow replace those whacky URLs with my own, "proper" URLs for the app, in a more persistent manner than is possible with a simple URL redirection?

I'd like to be able to navigate to `https://myapp.mycompany.com` for production, and stay on that URL, no matter what page of the app the user is on (e.g. `https://myapp.mycompany.com/login`, `https://myapp.mycompany.com/help`, `https://myapp.mycompany.com/somefeature` etc.) - so I don't want a simplistic URL redirect - it needs to be something more permanent.

Any ideas, thoughts?

Comment: They are called "auto-generated domain names". To use your own domain name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure Portal, find your app under Static Web Apps.

Go to `Custom Domains > Add > Custom domain on other DNS > yourapp.yourcompany.com > Next`.  (I'm assuming you're not using Azure DNS.  If you are, follow that path instead; I expect it's similarly easy).

It will then tell you the entries to add to your company's DNS server, which should just be a single CNAME.  Once (your network guys have that) added, wait perhaps 5 minutes (can take longer) and click `Add`.  If the new CNAME hasn't propagated yet, it will give an error, in which case wait a few more minutes and try again, until it succeeds.

I think there is then one more (obvious) click to do, then it takes a minute or two to get the SSL certificate.  After that you can use the new URL.

Edit: they have probably already used CNAMEs to do the redirections you describe, in which case just do the steps without the waiting-for-them bit.